# Error when creating virtualenv folder

Tags: virtualenv

I am working through the book Test Driven Devlopement, and am currently having a problem when I try to create a virtualenv folder using:

```
virtualenv --python=python3 ../virtualenv
```

I keep on getting this output:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\runpy.py", line 160, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\runpy.py", line 73, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python33\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 774, in main
    interpreter = resolve_interpreter(options.python)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1575, in resolve_interpreter
    python_versions = get_installed_pythons()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 93, in get_installed_pythons
    path = winreg.QueryValue(python_core, "%s\\InstallPath" % ver)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on windows:  ../virutalenv is for unix
On unix, you are telling virtualenv to create a virtualenv directory in the directory up one level (previous) also windows uses backslash instead of slash.

Try to find a tutorial that is windows oriented, or if you can get your hand on a unix/linux machine, or maybe install cygwin.

Comment: I ended up just using cygwin